# How is string multiplication implemented in CPython?

Tags: python, string, multiplication, cpython

Python allows the multiplication of strings by integers:

```
>>> 'hello' * 5
'hellohellohellohellohello'
```

How is this implemented in CPython?

I would particularly appreciate a pointer to the source code; [the Mercurial repository](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3) is a labyrinth beyond my abilities to navigate.

Comment: That's not how to use `dis` - when you pass it a string it interprets it as bytecode! Try passing a `lambda`.

Comment: @ecatmur What's worse, the `join()` was totally wrong - needs an iterator. I removed it (and will spend some time with `dis` docs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I'm going to answer for Python 3, where the string type is called `PyUnicode`. Python 2 is similar.

When a `BINARY_MULTIPLY` opcode is executed (in `Python/ceval.c`), there are two possible slots that can get called: `PyNumberMethods.nb_multiply` and `PySequenceMethods.sq_repeat`. (This is in `PyNumber_Multiply`, in `Objects/abstract.c`):

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_Multiply(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    PyObject *result = binary_op1(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_multiply));
    if (result == Py_NotImplemented) {
        // call sq_repeat on either side if available
```

`PyUnicode` implements the latter, in [`unicode_repeat`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4a86fe52006/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l12176):

```
static PyObject*
unicode_repeat(PyObject *str, Py_ssize_t len)
{
    // ...
```

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3.x, the implementation can be found in [`Objects/unicodeobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4a86fe52006/Objects/unicodeobject.c).  Specifically, it begins on [line 12175](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4a86fe52006/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l12175) where `unicode_repeat` is defined:

```c
static PyObject*
unicode_repeat(PyObject *str, Py_ssize_t len)
{
    PyObject *u;
    Py_ssize_t nchars, n;

    if (len < 1)
        _Py_RETURN_UNICODE_EMPTY();

    /* no repeat, return original string */
    if (len == 1)
        return unicode_result_unchanged(str);

    if (PyUnicode_READY(str) == -1)
        return NULL;

    if (PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(str) > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX / len) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
                        "repeated string is too long");
        return NULL;
    }
    nchars = len * PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(str);

    u = PyUnicode_New(nchars, PyUnicode_MAX_CHAR_VALUE(str));
    if (!u)
        return NULL;
    assert(PyUnicode_KIND(u) == PyUnicode_KIND(str));

    if (PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(str) == 1) {
        const int kind = PyUnicode_KIND(str);
        const Py_UCS4 fill_char = PyUnicode_READ(kind, PyUnicode_DATA(str), 0);
        if (kind == PyUnicode_1BYTE_KIND) {
            void *to = PyUnicode_DATA(u);
            memset(to, (unsigned char)fill_char, len);
        }
        else if (kind == PyUnicode_2BYTE_KIND) {
            Py_UCS2 *ucs2 = PyUnicode_2BYTE_DATA(u);
            for (n = 0; n < len; ++n)
                ucs2[n] = fill_char;
        } else {
            Py_UCS4 *ucs4 = PyUnicode_4BYTE_DATA(u);
            assert(kind == PyUnicode_4BYTE_KIND);
            for (n = 0; n < len; ++n)
                ucs4[n] = fill_char;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* number of characters copied this far */
        Py_ssize_t done = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(str);
        const Py_ssize_t char_size = PyUnicode_KIND(str);
        char *to = (char *) PyUnicode_DATA(u);
        Py_MEMCPY(to, PyUnicode_DATA(str),
                  PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(str) * char_size);
        while (done < nchars) {
            n = (done <= nchars-done) ? done : nchars-done;
            Py_MEMCPY(to + (done * char_size), to, n * char_size);
            done += n;
        }
    }

    assert(_PyUnicode_CheckConsistency(u, 1));
    return u;
}
```

Later, on [line 13703](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4a86fe52006/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l13703), this function is supplied as the [`sq_repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PySequenceMethods.sq_repeat) slot for the [`PySequenceMethods`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PySequenceMethods) of the `PyUnicode` object.